# iOS - Entry in Info.plist for only iOS 6 and above?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uifont, info.plist, font-replacement

I have an entry in my app's Info.plist (a Dictionary), and I only want it to be used in iOS 6 and above. It involves font replacement, using [FontReplacer](https://github.com/0xced/FontReplacer), and I don't want to replace fonts for a device running iOS 5. You can see the example on GitHub for a better explanation.

Basically, is there a way for me to only use that Info.plist entry if the user's device is running iOS 6 or later?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

### No.

There isn't a way to tell the system to only have a specific entry available if >iOS 6.

There is, however, a way to tell whether you're on an OS > 6 in code, though:

```
#ifdef IPHONE_6_0
    //...
#endif
```

Comment: Hmm, ok. Can I have multiple plists for different versions? Sorry if this is a bad question.

Comment: @mhbdr I'm pretty sure that there's no way to make that happen. I wish there was, though :)

Comment: @mhbdr Just curious, what did you want this for, exactly?

Comment: @Undo I posted a similar question over here with an example of why you need something like this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18998236/ios-version-specific-info-plist-settings