# iOS version specific info.plist settings

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, info.plist

I am in the process of updating an app for iOS7 (while still supporting iOS6), and have updated the status bar to use a white foreground using `UIStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyleLightContent`.

However the `UIStatusBarStyleLightContent` value is new in iOS7, and so when run on iOS6 the `UIStatusBarStyle` reverts back to `UIStatusBarStyleDefault`, giving the light-gray with dark text iOS6 default. But I need my iOS6 version to use the black style `UIStatusBarStyleBlackOpaque` status bar.

Given you can set info.plist settings for different device and platform types, e.g. `UIStatusBarStyle~ipad`:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/AdvancedAppTricks/AdvancedAppTricks.html

I know I can set the value at runtime via the `UIApplication`, but this doesn't have an affect until after the startup image has displayed.

I am hoping you can use a similar mechanism for iOS versions? e.g:

```
UIStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyleBlackOpaque
UIStatusBarStyle~ios7: UIStatusBarStyleLightContent
```

However that doesn't work and I can't find any apple documentation anywhere on such a feature. Am I out of luck and will have to live with the ugly white status bar during iOS6 app launches?

EDIT: Just found a similar question here: [iOS - Entry in Info.plist for only iOS 6 and above?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17286240/ios-entry-in-info-plist-for-only-ios-6-and-above)

Seems like the answer is no, this is not possible. Unless there have been any updates with iOS7?

Comment: you realise your edit gives a link back to this same question?! I think you re-found your own question!

Comment: @mattjgalloway hahaha, oops. must of copied wrong link. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Use this, As i think so, this will be helpful to you,

```
if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) <= NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_1) {
    // Load resources for iOS 6.1 or earlier, i.e set status bar here for previous versions 
} else {
    // Load resources for iOS 7 or later, set status bar here for ios 7 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I know I can update it at runtime (and I am already doing that actually). The problem is this doesnt have an affect until after the app starts and after the splash image has been shown. This causes it to change from the setting in the info.plist to the setting at runtime. My question is specifically about iOS specific `info.plist` settings.

Comment: It is actually better if you hide status bar during Launch time(when splash screen appears) by putting "Status bar is initially hidden" to YES in info.plist, and then update the status bar at runtime, because there is no any field in info.plist to do the problem you have specified