# iOS change shortcut name based on device

Tags: ios, sdk

Is it possible to have different display names depending on the device?

like iPhone App for iPhone, iPad App for iPad etc.

Michael.

Comment: Just place your question clear. Where you have to show display names? Did you mean by icon name?

Comment: ur question is similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18998236/ios-version-specific-info-plist-settings but its not possible so far